# raw socket in linux

Tags: networking

In my system there are two interfaces (eth0 and eth1).I want to know how to make my raw socket receive data only from one interface? Now if i open a raw socket using the call,

**S32_SocketFd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))**

it receives data from eth0, eth1 and lo.

Filtering these out is a tedious task for my system.
I am using linux kernel 4.14 (ubuntu). Please help.

Comment: You haven't said what release of Ubuntu you are using, but the kernel 4.14 is EOL in Ubuntu, being only supported as a *test* kernel.  What OS/release are you using?

Comment: Sorry I am worng about kernel version.My Ubuntu version: 18.04.3 LTS